# How can I use an array that I created with a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have made a function that generates an array of numbers. However, the array is not recognized anywhere else outside the function itself.

```
function arroyo (a, b){ // a = array length; b = integer order of magnitude
    var numbers = new Array();
    var num;
    var mag;
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) { // integer generator
        num = 0;
        for (var j = 1; j <= b; j++) { // adding numbers @ required magnitude
        mag = Math.pow(10,j);
        num = num + Math.random()*mag;
    }
    numbers[i] = Math.round(num);
}
```

How can I use the variable `numbers` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return`, in order to access the array outside the function. 
Declare a new variable and initialise it with the returned array generated by your function `let numbersArr = arroyo(2, 2)`

```js
function arroyo(a, b) { // a = array length; b = integer order of magnitude
  var numbers = new Array();
  var num;
  var mag;
  for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) { // integer generator
    num = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j <= b; j++) { // adding numbers @ required magnitude
      mag = Math.pow(10, j);
      num = num + Math.random() * mag;
    }
    numbers[i] = Math.round(num);
  }
  
  return numbers;
}

let numbersArr = arroyo(2, 2)
console.log(numbersArr) // print the array

for(let i in numbersArr){
  console.log("number [" + i +"] " + numbersArr[i]) // print each element from array
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I wasn't sure of how exactly I should use `return`. I had the impression that it was not always necessary.